# Error in OAuthException in Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram-api

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}
```

I already have **client id** and **secret id**. My redirect url is http://localhost. And I also obtained curlhttpclient.php, instagram.php, and example.php from macuenca in github. I modified the example.php and replaced client id, secret, id, and redirect url with mine. But everytime i run the example.php, i get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register with Instragram to get your OAuth client_id and client_secret OAuth, you register the URL you intend to redirect to after authentication.  That is not matching the URL you are using (localhost).

Likely either you need to

(a) Update your instagram registration, or
 (b) You are using someone elses secret token, so register your own

More information:
https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en
https://instagram.com/developer/register/

Comment: I am making an app that generates pictures from instagram, by making the user type their desired hashtag-title (e.g. #example), and then output it. Now, I already have a registration page, a login page, and just a simple webpage with a textbox where users can input hashtag.

Comment: I don't know where would I start. Like, where will I put this codes that I saw. Should I insert it in the webpage where the textbox (insert hashtag box) was located?

Comment: Your problem is nothing to do with the application, you need to tell instagram that "http://localhost" is an acceptable redirect_uri for your client_id.  You need to login to the instagram developer portal and set that.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect URL must be absolute URL i.e. something like

```
http://localhost/callback.php
```

and then make an authentication call from this page itself i.e **callback.php**, otherwise it will not let you to fetch access token, as well pass the complete URL in **redirect_url** filed